# MacOSx Lion AirDrop peers discovery method

Tags: macos, network-protocols, bonjour

Does the MacOSx 10.7 (Lion) AirDrop peers discovery method using the Bonjour (MDNS) technology, or the WiFi Direct Peer-to-Peer technology (http://www.wi-fi.org/Wi-Fi_Direct.php) ?

I remember Bonjour only works within link-local network. But I have seen articles saying AirDrop can work across different networks or SSID.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Otherwise, it's better suited for http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: 10.7 is under NDA, so no one will answer your question. Btw, there is something called wide area bonjour that works outside the LAN.

Answer (score 2):

AirDrop does use mDNS.

ifconfig shows that a new network interface called p2p[1-N] is created when AirDrop is opened. Sniffing traffic on this interface shows mDNSv6 packets being sent to ff02::fd port 5353. Containing the strings "_airdrop", your machine name and so on.

But I haven't been able to determine anything about the radio link layer.